# Can we Overload api based on content Type in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I have requirement having Api which consumes URL encoded data and Application JSON both behave in different way with same end point

Answer (score 0):

no it does not work like that 
it will work as per request mapping like get post optional update etc

but you can tweak and complete your work  like

```
//Post method #1
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/foo", headers="returnType=withoutcertainformat")
public @ResponseBody Foo updateFoo(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
    fooService.update(foo);
}

//Post method #2
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/foo", headers="returnType=withcertainformat")
public @ResponseBody FooExtra updateFoo(@RequestBody FooExtra fooExtra) {
    fooService.update(fooExtra);
}
```